# Can't update my Android app because of not matching fingerprints

Tags: android, google-play, apk, fingerprint

I have an Android app on Google Play.
I cannot update it, since I didn't know that if I create a new `Keystore.jks` file, I won't be able to update it. Also, I permanently deleted the first one.
Can I update my app anyway?
if I need to completely remove it from Google Play, I will.
I prefer to keep the existing package name.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't update it if you sign it with any other keystore.You need to use the same signing keys to update it.